# Using the taskkill command with a timer?

Tags: windows, command-line, sleep, batch-file

I using a custom .bat file that closes my chrome browser, but can't seem to find information on what syntax I need to add in order for the process to end after a given amount of time.  Can anyone, at least, point me in the right direction?

As an example of what I am trying to do, I want chrome to close 30 minutes from when I execute the following .bat file: taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe*  I imagine I am missing something quite simply here.

Cheers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672338/how-to-sleep-for-5-seconds-in-windowss-command-prompt-or-dos

Answer (score 3):

you can insert before your command

```
timeout /t 3600
```

which will pause your batch for 3600 seconds (60 minutes).